# AutoSuggestBox implementation in windows 8.1

Tags: xaml, autocomplete, windows-8.1, windows, autosuggest

I need to implement an AutoSuggestBox in windows 8.1 application. My goal is to have a text box, which suggests and auto completes the text the user types.

Being a newbie, I don't know a lot about app development. I am not familiar with data binding either which seems to be crucial for this. So please be simple.

Answer (score 0):

Simple code behind example.

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
    public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; private set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        Items = new ObservableCollection<string>
        {
            "test",
            "new",
            "to",
            "test1"
        };
    }

    private void autosuggest_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        List<string> myList = new List<string>();
        foreach (string myString in Items)
        {
            if (myString.Contains(sender.Text) == true)
            {
                myList.Add(myString);
            }
        }
        sender.ItemsSource = myList;
    }
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<AutoSuggestBox x:Name="autosuggest" Foreground="White" TextChanged="autosuggest_TextChanged" />
```